# is it possible to use a list of labels in kivy

Tags: kivy

I have an application in kivy that uses many labels. Is it possible to obtain their values from a list? e.g. (but this doesn't work)

```
        Label:
            text:root.label_value[0]
        Label:
            text:root.label_value[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, quick example

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


Builder.load_string("""
<Test>:
    Label:
        text:root.label_value[0]
    Label:
        text:root.label_value[1]
""")

class Test(BoxLayout):

    label_value = ListProperty(["crazy", 'cheese'])

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.label_value = ["crazy2", 'cheese2']





class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks Yoav. That's the one I was looking for

Comment: Why is the list declared twice?

Comment: @Guglie The 2nd line is only to that the value can be changed and the view is updated... Its **not** a 2nd declaration ...

Comment: All right, now that I learned a bit of kivy usage I understand that was a trivial question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. A list can hold any kind of object in it. Consider the following code:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

labels = []
for i in range(10):
    labels.append(Label(text = str(i)))
```

Now you have a list containing 10 labels, all having their position in the list as a text. Having created the list you can access it like you normally would. The following code takes the labels from the previous example and adds them to a grid layout:

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
for item in labels:
    layout.add_widget(item)
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are available answers, I hope this will show you another, hopefully more pretty and/or efficient way.

Each widget when it's added to another widget as a child is then present in `<widget>.children` i.e. a *list* of objects which works in this way:

```
<widget>.children = [last_added, added before the `last_added` one, etc...]
```

With this way you don't need any additional variables to get/set values of your widgets. You can simply set `id` in `kv` file or have a parent object(widget) available in a variable so that you could do this:

```
print my_parent.children[0].text
print self.ids.my_parent.children[0].text
```

Which is basically what @Alan purposed, but without the unnecessary variable - you can just add them with `for` and access later from existing list.

@Yoav sets it in `__init__`, but you are dependent on that list, which means to add another `Label` you'd need to update that list. Or the other way around - additional function `on_label_value()`, which would check for length and add a new widget or remove widget `if len(new_label_value) != len(label_value)` or a similar case and if the new one would equal the old length of the list, then would do nothing. And this only complicates things in a large scale.

If you have a lot of (nested) widgets, your statements will become *long*, but there are ways to make them short e.g. using `ObjectProperty` and setting it in kv or using an additional property in an `App` class such as:

```
# python
app = App.get_running_app()
app.my_parent = self

# kv
app.my_parent # because in kv you have access to `App` with `app` keyword
```

In this way you can access pretty much anything, because you save the object you want to access somewhere you could access it easily from.